# Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Steps to reproduce problem

a) Prepare an extension with all the code below

b) Go to https://stackoverflow.com/

c) Click on "Top Questions: heading[image]

You will get an error saying *"Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"*

***Manifest file***

```
  {
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is a demo",

  "content_scripts": [ {
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["contentscript1.js" ],
        "matches": [ "https://stackoverflow.com/" ]
        }]
  }
```

***Editor.html file***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="editor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

***Editor.js file***

```
function onRequest(message,sender,call){ 
     document.getElementById("content").value = message; 
}
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```

***contentscript1.js***

```
function bindevent(){ 
window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("editor.html"),"_blank","toolbar=no, titlebar=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=yes, width=720, height=400");
    message = "Sample Message"; 
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(message,function (res){}); 

}; 

document.getElementById('h-top-questions').onclick=bindevent;
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: What is this "HTML Page which is not the default_popup html file"?

Comment: This HTML Page contains 'code'<label><b>File Name:</b></label><span id="title"></span> 'code' and the span is the reciever of content; More over this page is opened through window.open() on click of icon which is also injected in DOM

Comment: there are 2 html files in my .crx 1) The file which is opened when browser action icon is clicked 2) The file i am referring to

Comment: If you use `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, all extension's pages will receive the message, iirc. So, you can just listen to the event using `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function() { ... });` in the "external HTML file", and use `chrome.extension.sendMessage` from the content script. No BG involvement needed.

Comment: Is it like all the HTML Pages in .crx package can listen to messages from chrome.extension.sendMessage through chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function() { ... }); ???

Comment: But i get Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. error now; Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your code, make sure that you're creating a receiver before sending a message.

Comment: @Sudan Works fine here (after many modifications to fix some errors). Can you create a **small** extension which shows your real problem?

Comment: @RobW I have updated question content, can you figure out problem?

Comment: Because you're sending the message before the window is created.

Comment: Even though i opened window before sending message problem still occurs... Edited problem statement as well.. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, send the message *after* the window has been loaded. **OR** Pass the data through the URL fragment, ie `chrome.extension.getURL('editor.html') + '#datahere'` PS. In the future, don't change your question radically after the original problem has been solved. Now, many of the previous comments look a bit weird in the context of the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sending message while child window/extension page is still loading; I have sent message after it loaded completely and it solved my problem.

Final Code

***Manifest file***

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is a demo",

  "content_scripts": [ {
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["contentscript1.js" ],
        "matches": [ "http://stackoverflow.com/" ]
        }]
  }
```

***Editor.html file***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="editor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

***Editor.js File***

```
var message = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

***contentscript1.js***

```
   function bindevent(){
 message = "Sample Message"; 
    window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("editor.html")+"#"+message,"_blank","toolbar=no, titlebar=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=yes, width=720, height=400");
    }; 

document.getElementById('h-top-questions').onclick=bindevent
```

;